# why I am getting object not set to instance when i call webrequest.create with a uri that does not exist

Tags: c#, forms

I am testing out a browser am creating,
if i send a uri that exists to webrequest, everything is find,
but i get an object not set to instance when i send a uri that does not exist
such a http://www.bgdygjhcu.com

I expect the method to throw a not found exception. here is the method call

```
String stream = await Task.Run(() => web.Navigate("http://www.yahoo2gh.com"));
```

and here is the method that does the work

```
public async Task<String> Navigate(string uri)
{

 HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
 try
 {
     using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
     {
         HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
         //Set StatusCode
         StatusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode.ToString();
         //Create Stream
         Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
         StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

         return reader.ReadToEnd();

     }

 }
 catch (WebException exception)
 {
     using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)exception.Response)
     {
         // HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
         StatusCodeInteger = (int)response.StatusCode;

         //return httpResponse;
         return "empty";// response.StatusCode.ToString();
     }

 }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug and see what line exactly gives you the error? or see the stack trace?